# React Native RCTCustomScrollView broken after upgrading to Xcode8

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook, react-native

Apparently, [this is a well known issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8472) for react native when upgrading to Xcode 8. I have followed [this](https://yanqiw.github.io/2016/10/05/react-native-adopt-to-xcode8.html) guide to fix the error I am having, but I still get the following error when my app tries to load a `<ScrollView/>` component.

`[RCTCustomScrollView refreshControl]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16099e00`

The code in my `RCTScrollView.m` that everybody seems to think causes the problem is shown below:

```
- (void)setRefreshControl:(RCTRefreshControl *)refreshControl
{
  if (refreshControl) {
    [refreshControl removeFromSuperview];
  }
  refreshControl = refreshControl;
  [self addSubview:refreshControl];
}

- (void)removeReactSubview:(UIView *)subview
{
  if ([subview isKindOfClass:[RCTRefreshControl class]]) {
  _scrollView.refreshControl = nil;
  } else {
    RCTAssert(_contentView == subview, @"Attempted to remove non-existent subview");
    _contentView = nil;
    [subview removeFromSuperview];
  }
}
```

Everything seems to work fine when I run this on a device running iOS 10.1.1, but when I try on a device running 9.3, it crashes when it tries to load a `<ScrollView/>`.

**Important Note**
- I am running react native 0.28 and am in a tight situation where I can't upgrade right now, thus I have to make the fixes manually.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an older post, but for Xcode 8, iOS 9.3 (iPad 2/iPad Mini), React Native 0.24.1, I made this change in RCTScrollView.m as a fix.

```
@implementation RCTCustomScrollView
{
  __weak UIView *_dockedHeaderView;

 // Added the following line
 RCTRefreshControl *_refreshControl;
}
// Also added this
@synthesize refreshControl = _refreshControl;
```

Comment: it's helpful for me. Thank a lots

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found is this, go to RCTScrollView.m and replace `[_scrollView refreshControl]` with `[_scrollView respondsToSelector: @selector(refreshControl)]`

```
- (NSArray<UIView *> *)reactSubviews
{
  if (_contentView && [_scrollView respondsToSelector: @selector(refreshControl)]) {
    return @[_contentView, [_scrollView refreshControl]];
  }
  return _contentView ? @[_contentView] : @[];
}
```